# How to add two nested python dictionaries?

Tags: python

```
    a= {u'1009': {u'Avg': 188,
      u'amount_spent': 2820,
      u'size': 15,
      u'users': {u'0': 346041,
       u'1': 658546,
       u'2': 658194,
       u'3': 658316
       }},
    u'1056': {u'Avg': 140,
      u'amount_spent': 140,
      u'size': 1,
      u'users': {u'0': 645767}},
     u'1103': {u'Avg': 95,
      u'amount_spent': 285,
      u'size': 3,
      u'users': {u'0': 339285, u'1': 658440}}
b = {u'1009': {u'Avg': 246.25,
  u'amount_spent': 1970,
  u'size': 8,
  u'users': {u'0': 61496,
   u'1': 1350,
   u'2': 164852,
   u'3': 517760,
   u'4': 576458,
   u'5': 203840,
   u'6': 52239,
   u'7': 516672}},
 u'1056': {u'Avg': 170,
  u'amount_spent': 680,
  u'size': 4,
  u'users': {u'0': 503737, u'1': 624418, u'2': 642471}}}
```

I have multiple nested dictionaries, which I wanted to merge and add by their inner keys, so my output looked something like this.

```
c = {u'1009': {u'Avg': 434.25,
  u'amount_spent': 4790,
  u'size': 23,
  u'users': {u'0': 61496,
   u'1': 1350,
   u'2': 164852,
   u'3': 517760,
   u'4': 576458,
   u'5': 203840,
   u'6': 52239,
   u'7': 516672,
   u'8': 346041,
   u'9': 658546,
   u'10': 658194,
   u'11': 658316
}},,,,,
```

The idea is to just add the values for the keys that are already present. If they aren't just add the new key instead. Adding them with `+` opperand doesn't work. Any idea on how i could do this ?

EDIT1:
A lot of the issues in merging the users key was due to the values being user_id themselves. Hence they can't be added, rather just appended in the users key. One way to solve this issue was through making the value for users key as an array :

```
{u'1009': {u'Avg': 188,
  u'amount_spent': 2820,
  u'size': 15,
  u'users': [346041,
   658546,
   658194,
   658316]},
 u'1056': {u'Avg': 140, u'amount_spent': 140, u'size': 1, u'users': [645767]}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: You can use `if` condition to test for the `keys` in the dictionary and use the `append` method to add the values

Comment: Is it the innermost keys you want to merge on, or a particular level? It's not clear from your description and your example is not clear

Comment: I wanted to merge on the innermost keys.

Comment: In your example, the `users` of  `1009` don't add up. Why? Is it an error in your post or else?

Comment: I had to manually add them up, for the sake of showing an output, but the total number of users should be shown.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some idea to tinker with, this recursive function adds the content of the dictionaries together.

```
def add_dict(x, y):
    n = {}
    inter = x.keys() & y.keys()
    outer = (x.keys() | y.keys()) - inter

    for k in x.keys() & y.keys():
        l, r = x[k], y[k]
        if isinstance(l, dict):
            n[k] = add_dict(l, r)
            continue
        n[k] = l + r

    for k in outer:
        l, r = x.get(k), y.get(k)
        if l: n[k] = l
        if r: n[k] = r

    return n

c = add_dict(a, b)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a function that recursively iterates over k,v of two dictionaries and sums the value of the common keys (be aware of the consequences in case of sum of strings). The keys not in common are also included in the final dictionary that is then returned.

I am not sure this is what you are looking for since, in your example, the values of some common keys are added together while others are not.

I hope this can be a good starting point for you.

```
def merge_dict(dictA, dictB):
    r = {}

    common_k = [k for k in dictA if k in dictB]
    common_k += [k for k in dictB if k in dictA]
    common_k = set(common_k)

    for k, v in dictA.items():
        #add unique k of dictA
        if k not in common_k:
            r[k] = v

        else:
            #add inner keys if they are not containing other dicts 
            if type(v) is not dict:
                if k in dictB:
                    r[k] = v + dictB[k]
            else:
                #recursively merge the inner dicts
                r[k] = merge_dict(dictA[k], dictB[k])

    #add unique k of dictB
    for k, v in dictB.items():
        if k not in common_k:
            r[k] = v

    return r


#test
dictA = {'any key':1, 'point':{'x':2, 'y':3}}
dictB = {'any key':1, 'point':{'x':2, 'y':3, 'z':0, 'even more nested':{'w':99}}, 'extra':8}
merge_dict(dictA, dictB)

{'any key': 2,
 'point': {'x': 4, 'y': 6, 'z': 0, 'even more nested': {'w': 99}},
 'extra': 8}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use recursion with a dictionary comprehension:

```
import itertools
a = {'1009': {'Avg': 188, 'amount_spent': 2820, 'size': 15, 'users': {'0': 346041, '1': 658546, '2': 658194, '3': 658316}}, '1056': {'Avg': 140, 'amount_spent': 140, 'size': 1, 'users': {'0': 645767}}, '1103': {'Avg': 95, 'amount_spent': 285, 'size': 3, 'users': {'0': 339285, '1': 658440}}}
b = {'1009': {'Avg': 246.25, 'amount_spent': 1970, 'size': 8, 'users': {'0': 61496, '1': 1350, '2': 164852, '3': 517760, '4': 576458, '5': 203840, '6': 52239, '7': 516672}}, '1056': {'Avg': 170, 'amount_spent': 680, 'size': 4, 'users': {'0': 503737, '1': 624418, '2': 642471}}}
def full_sum(d1, d2):
  v1 = {a:list(b) for a, b in itertools.groupby(sorted(list(d1.items())+list(d2.items()), key=lambda x:x[0]), key=lambda x:x[0])}
  return {a:sum(_i for h, _i in b) if all(not isinstance(i, dict) for d, i in b) else full_sum(*[i for _, i in b]) for a, b in v1.items()}

def add_dicts(_a, _b):
   return {c:full_sum(d, f) for [c, d], [e, f] in zip(_a.items(), _b.items())}

print(add_dicts(a, b))
```

Output:

```
{'1009': {'Avg': 434.25, 'amount_spent': 4790, 'size': 23, 'users': {'0': 407537, '1': 659896, '2': 823046, '3': 1176076, '4': 576458, '5': 203840, '6': 52239, '7': 516672}}, '1056': {'Avg': 310, 'amount_spent': 820, 'size': 5, 'users': {'0': 1149504, '1': 624418, '2': 642471}}}
```